# Developing for Twilio from outside the US (South America)

Tags: debugging, twilio, voip, skype

We have a developer who is working on our Twilio code. He is located in Boliva. The problem is that he needs to be able to make and receive calls in order to test the Twilio code. As far as I know, phone numbers in Bolivia are not supported by Twilio.

What is a good workaround for this. Can skype or some other voip solution be used so that he can have a US-based number for debugging?

Thanks!

Comment: Would Google Talk not work?  (I.e: have you had him try something *like* Google Talk, which is free)

Comment: Just tried google voice. It wouldn't work because the number they gave us needed to be from the same country as his number. (So both numbers needed to be in Bolivia)

Comment: Ahh! Glad you tried it. Bummer it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it was good suggestion, I wouldn't have tried it had you not said anything.

Comment: Have you tried emailing support at Twillio? I regularly get (computer generated) emails from support guys there asking if I have any questions...perhaps they have an idea?

Comment: Gmail has chat in the browser.. he could get a US number from GV and then listen for calls inside Gmail

Comment: @Christopher Pfohl - I did, actually I posted to their "getsatisfaction" forum because it seemed like something they might want to answer publicly. They do seem to have good support and I've actually talked to one of their founders on the phone before.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow Nice. That's awesome.  Definitely post whatever response they have here. Sounds like a useful question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are hundreds of VoIP providers which sell you an US number for a few bucks per month, and the incoming calls would be delivered to you via SIP. So you just need a SIP client to connect to such provider, and the calls to your US number would land on your desk.

Search keywords: "DID Number", "Virtual number".

Recently I used http://www.sipglobalphone.com/ to get a free iNUM number, and they also offer US numbers at low price.

Also there are services alternative to Twilio. For example, http://www.plivo.org/  is an open-source product with similar features.